# Security setting for WCF service requires anonymous authentication

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF service but getting following error.
Error: Security service for this service require Anonymous authentication.
I found similar problems but their solution did not work for me.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CMSUI.DataServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">


          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="CMSUI.DataService" >
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="CMSUI.DataServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CMSUI.DataService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am using windows authentication and I don't want to enable anonymous access.

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS? Does the site/application have anonymous authentication enabled?

Comment: Yes I am hosting using IIS and anonymous authentication is not enabled and I don't want to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being i enabled anonymous access in iis and disabled anonymous access in web.config. It solved my problem.

web.config

```
 <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*"/>
 </authorization>
```